# App freeze after calling dynamicRealm.beginTransaction()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

When i am calling  `dynamicRealm.beginTransaction();` nothing happening simply app getting freeze.
below is the code:

```
Realm saverealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); 
final DynamicRealm dynamicRealm = 
           DynamicRealm.getInstance(saverealm.getConfiguration());
final RealmSchema realmSchema = dynamicRealm.getSchema();
dynamicRealm.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: format your code to make it easy to understand.

Comment: @Mak-MakBasaya please check now.

Comment: That means you already have a transaction open on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

If the Transaction is already happening, this will lead to crash of the app, the correct way is :-

```
try {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    // body of executeTransaction
    realm.commitTransaction();
} catch(Exception e) { 
    if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
         realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

or just do

```
realm.executeTransaction()
```

See this for more info :- https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4217

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason of app freezes is blocking the UI thread or main thread. Avoid longer operations like db interaction on this thread. Use RxJava with realm and switch to worker thread when doing db transactions.